# Automatically partitioning C/C++ source code into distributed applications

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, rpc

Is it possible to write take a C or C++ source file and automatically create client/server implementations of the functions in the source file without the need for an interface definition language? Consider the following example:

**prog.c**

```
int foo() {
  return 2;
}
```

I would like to split `foo.c` into two files: `client.c` and `server.c` as follows:

**client.c**

```
int foo() {
  return server_foo();
}
```

**server.c**

```
int server_foo() {
  return 2;
}
```

I would like `server.c` to run on a separate machine than the one running `client.c`, so I need to implement some form of RPC. Everything I've researched (ONC RPC, XML RPC, Apache Thrift...) requires manual definition of function prototypes in an interface file. Is there any way to feed `prog.c` to a program which can automatically generate the distributed application source code?

Note: I want these programs to run on a Unix system!

Comment: You should explain much more what your `prog.c` is actually doing.

Comment: And **why do you ask** ?

Comment: I ask because I want to automate some of the arduous tasks associated with distributed application development. It is a huge pain to write interface definitions, generate stubs, and implement those stubs. Wouldn't it be nice to have a way of automatically generating those implementations in C++ instead of having to do it by hand?

Comment: If your application is big enough, you could automatize part of the work, see my answer. But there is no silver bullet.

Comment: I understand there will be no magic fix-all for this problem. If I could do this for functions which perform common privileged operations, that'd actually be enough. For example, I might want all functions dealing with file and environment variable access to occur in a privileged process while a non-privileged process simply asks the privileged process to perform those operations on its behalf. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You could automatize part of the job, as I explained in my answer. I can't tell if it is worth the effort, you really should explain much more what your `prog.c` is (or can be), and what kind of application is it and what is your application domain....

Comment: `prog.c` can be any application which deals with privileged operations such as file access and environment variable access. There is a security concern with setuid programs because if an attacker exploits a program with root privileges, then the attacker can wreak havoc. If we move all privileged operations to a separate process (possibly on a different machine) and drop all privileges from the "original" process, then we downsize the amount of damage an attacker can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in general (in particular because there is no general way to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) *arbitrary* C data (or C++ data), like e.g. some `FILE*` handle or some `void*` pointer -e.g. obtained by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) ..., or some C++11 instance of `std::thread`).

<sup>In general it is not possible: a shared memory is not the same as a collection of agents with message passing.</sup>

But we could assume that your `prog.c` has only functions involving easily serializable types. This is a strong hypothesis which is usually not true. (for instance, if you represent a tree, or some directed acyclic graph, using some `struct`-s, the C code does not know that it is a tree or a DAG and how it should be serialized; and if your data structure represents a more general *graph*  you should know much more than its C coded types to serialize it, since its naive serialization would be infinite... because we don't know what is the shareable data...).

Also, even if all your types are serializable, you don't want in practice to distribute every function. For example, doing a remote call when computing `strlen` of strings does not make sense in practice: computing the `strlen` locally is thousands -or millions- of time faster than making a remote procedure call (even to an infinitely fast remote server, given the current networking delays; an RPC takes several milliseconds to transmit and receive data).

<sup>So you have to cleverly choose, within your `prog.c`, which functions you want to distribute on a remote server.</sup>

For example, if `prog.c` contains the following function:

```
// return a heap-allocated string to be free-d by caller
char* make_name(int x) {
   char buf[24];
   snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "NAME_%d", x);
   return strdup(buf);
}
```

you don't want to distribute it. Making an RPC call from it does not make any practical sense.

However, you might for instance consider customizing [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (assuming you have a recent version e.g. 4.7 or 4.8) with your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension which handle some common cases automatically.

<sup>MELT is a lisp-y domain specific language, implemented as a GCC [meta-]plugin, to extend GCC</sup>

So you could code your extension in *MELT* for `gcc` (and `g++`) which would process `prog.c` (while GCC is compiling it) and dump appropriate glue code (e.g. some`prog_generated.x` file for ONC RPC...), at least for those functions whose signature involve serializable types.

<sup>The issue is to define what exactly are your serializable types and how you serialize them (and what are the routines you want to distribute remotely); then you'll spend a week -or more- to code that MELT extension. Please ask on [`gcc-melt@googlegroups.com` list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gcc-melt) for help and advices. You could consider adding your own `#pragma`-s and/or your own `__attribute__` to guide the serialization and the remote distribution...</sup>

See also [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), [message-passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-passing) and [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing_interface) wikipages...

Comment: Would it be possible to determine which C/C++ types are serializable by examining the LLVM IR output from a compilation of `c.prog` using clang? If so, I could dump the glue code  for `prog_generated.x`  during an LLVM compiler pass.

Comment: I have no idea (because I don't know much LLVM internals, only GCC ones), but I believe that not. `FILE*` are not serializable for deep reasons (that an integer Unix file descriptor is not an ordinary integer).  I guess that for your purposes LLVM extensions are similar to GCC ones (using MELT). The `struct _IO_FILE*` (that is, `FILE*` on Linux) looks like a serializable one, but is not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool to generate the client/server code based on the c/c++ source code, just use Apache Thrift, as you already know, it only requires you to write the DDL(data definition language). then it can generate the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I am responding after the OP accepted the answer...

We have developed a tool(internet function call compiler, ifcc) that generates distributed
applications. It uses C language itself as an IDL.  The function calling arguments are treated as 'request' and the function return value as 'response'.  It also does arbitrary pointer chasing. I.e. it serializes/deserialisizes nested structures, pointers, typedefs, etc. E.g. a pointer to a tree or a doubly linked list will be serialized by the client stub and deserialized by the server stub.

A response that is other than a primitive data type is returned via a pointer to struct, typedef or as char *.  The client has to free the memory when it no longer needs the response.

The generated C source code uses ONC RPC/XDR routines at the lower level.

We are currently integrating browser based visibility into the generated code so that one can get runtime visibility into distributed applications.  This effort is part of C-Parallel programing for many-core processors where the problem is similar to creating distributed applications. For more information of where C-Parallel fits in with many-core and distributed applications, see the slides for '*Easy Parallel Programming for Scalable Many-core and Distributed Applications In C with Just Four Keywords*' at [ac.accord.com/doc/c-parallel.pdf](http://ac.accord.com/doc/c-parallel.pdf).

Ifcc is a prototype compiler for us to experiment and learn what is needed to easily create application management ready and scalable distributed + many-core applications with C-Parallel.

For those of you who are interested in experimenting with ifcc, we could make it available for external use. The current tool will generate distributed application that can be used with TCP/UDP and remote calls will be synchronous.  C-Parallel will allow asynchronous calls when completed.

It may take couple of weeks or so to make the ifcc available for external use.  Any feedback we get would be useful to us in getting C-Parallel right.  Disclosure: I work for Accord Software, Inc.

If interested in test driving ifcc, please let me know.

Comment: Arun, I am very interested in hearing more about your work. How can I reach out to you outside of StackOverflow?

Comment: You can reach me at arun.taylor@gmail.com